# Python remove from json dict doesn't work

Tags: python, json

When i call this function to remove an item from a dict imported from json it doesn't work

```
def removeKey(key):
    with open ("keys.json") as f:
        data  = json.loads(f.read())
        for d in data["keys"]:
            if(d["key"] == key):
                del d

    print(data)

    with open ("keys.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

This is how the dict is set up in JSON

```
{"keys": [
    {"key": 1599853953652, "role": "MODERATOR", "Server": 753230650181550141, "uses": 1, "maxuses": 0}
    ]
}
```

Comment: `del d` only removes the variable `d`, it doesn't modify the dict.

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want to delete. What would `key` look like, and what do you want the final result to be? Are you deleting an entire dict from the list of dicts inside "keys", or are you removing a particular key/value pair?

Comment: can you explain exactly why this condition `if(d["key"] == key)`? do you want to delete a dictionary inside list where values equal to `key`

Comment: Just to specify a bit better (my mistake) The "keys" dict has a list of dicts each with unique id's. I am looking to find the one where the key = to the key passed with the function. Then i want to delete the object that said key is present in (key, role, server etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you actually want to remove any dictionaries in the list of dicts under `"keys"` if the value of their `"key"` entry matches a certain number (e.g. `1599853953652`).

Assuming that's the case, the cleanest approach is actually to create a new list that filters out the unwanted entries; you can't simply call `del` to remove an element while iterating.

```
data = json.loads(f.read())
filtered_keys = [d for d in data["keys"] if d["key"] != key]
data["keys"] = filtered_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in data["keys"]:
    if(d["key"] == key):
        del d
```

`del` deletes *names*.  Deleting a name does not delete the associated value, unless it was the *only* name for the value.

The `for d in ...` loop creates `d` as an additional *name* for `data["keys"]["key"]`.  When you `del d`, you are *only* deleting the name `d` -- you are *not* deleting the value from `data`.

This is equivalent to:

```
x = 1
y = x
del y
```

After running this code, `x` still exists.  `del y` just removed the *name* `y`.

To put it another way, think of post-it notes stuck onto boxes.  The post-it notes are *names*, and the boxes are *values*.  One box can have many notes stuck on it, and removing a note doesn't destroy the box (unless it was the *only* note).

Answer (score 0):

remove 'role'  -  one liner demo

```
data = {"keys": [
    {"key": 1599853953652, "role": "MODERATOR", "Server": 753230650181550141, "uses": 1, "maxuses": 0}
    ]
}

data['keys'][0].pop('role',None)
print(data)
```

output

```
{'keys': [{'key': 1599853953652, 'Server': 753230650181550141, 'uses': 1, 'maxuses': 0}]}
```

Comment: what if the length of the list is greater than 1?

Comment: it's not a case in example  input what if the input changes

Comment: It will contain more items but this was just for testing but i have found an answer

Comment: @JanuZz_dk Great. Next time please share the actual input.

Answer (score 0):

Using `del d` only deletes the variable `d` but doesn't affect the list you want to remove from. You need operate on the list itself. I would use the `pop()` method, although `del` would work too.

```py
def removeKey(key):
    with open ("keys.json") as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
        for i, d in enumerate(data["keys"]):
            if d["key"] == key:
                data["keys"].pop(i)

    print(data)

    with open ("keys.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```